# Cast base class to inherited class from deserialized collection in java

Tags: java, json, serialization, casting, deserialization

I have a base class

**SocialRecord.java**

```
public class SocialRecord{

    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

and two derived classes

**SocialEmailRecord.java**

```
public class SocialEmailRecord extends SocialRecord{

        private String subject;

        public String getSubject() {
            return subject;
        }

        public void setSubject(String subject) {
            this.subject = subject;
        }
}
```

**SocialDiscussionRecord.java**

```
public class SocialDiscussionRecord extends SocialRecord{

    private String source;

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

}
```

I create some instances of SocialEmailRecord and SocialDiscussionRecord classes.

```
SocialEmailRecord r1 = new SocialEmailRecord();
r1.setSubject("sub1");
SocialEmailRecord r2 = new SocialEmailRecord();
r2.setSubject("sub2");
SocialDiscussionRecord r3 = new SocialDiscussionRecord();
r3.setSource("source3");
SocialDiscussionRecord r4 = new SocialDiscussionRecord();
r4.setSource("source4");
```

I add these objects to a collection.

```
List<SocialRecord> records = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(r1, r2, r3, r4));
```

I serialize this collection by gson.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String objsInJson = gson.toJson(records);
```

Now I would like to deserialize this collection, but I don't know how to construct original objects of collection.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Object>>() {}.getType();
List records = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(graphUtils.getGson().fromJson(objsInJson), listType)));
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++){
            if (records.get(i).getClass().equals(SocialDiscussionRecord.class))
                records.set(i, (SocialDiscussionRecord) records.get(i));
            if (records.get(i).getClass().equals(SocialPhoneRecord.class))
                records.set(i, (SocialPhoneRecord) records.get(i));
            if (records.get(i).getClass().equals(SocialEmailRecord.class))
                records.set(i, (SocialEmailRecord) records.get(i));
            if (records.get(i).getClass().equals(SocialRecord.class))
                records.set(i, (SocialRecord) records.get(i));
        }
```

Comment: So you're trying to convert your `ArrayList<Object>` into an `ArrayList<SocialRecord>`?  Why not just use `TypeToken<ArrayList<SocialRecord>>` as `listType`?

Comment: If you do this you lost value of attribute "source" of SocialDiscussionRecord class and "subject" of SocialEmailRecord class

Comment: Oh, right you are.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to implement a `TypeHierarchyAdapter` and [register it to the GsonBuilder](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) that will manage the deserialisation of the specificities of each subclass.

[See here for a full classical example with `Employee/Manager`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/test/java/com/google/gson/functional/TypeHierarchyAdapterTest.java)

But then you will get an `ArrayList<SocialRecord>` even if the object instances are actual `SocialEmailRecord` or `SocialDiscussionRecord`. You need to define some methods in `SocialRecord` that shall be overridden in the subclasses and use polymorphism to process the list.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution and it works https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=43#c15